# WCF Access Denied exception never returns to client after CheckAccessCore

Tags: c#, wcf, security, wcf-security, access-denied

I have a WCF service configured with `TransportWithMessageCredential` security. All the three implementations for `IAuthorizationPolicy`, `ServiceAuthenticationManager` and `ServiceAuthorizationManager` are in place and effective.

```
serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate("CN=localhost");
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomValidator();
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;

serviceHost.Authorization.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
serviceHost.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new MyServiceAuthorizationManager();
serviceHost.Authentication.ServiceAuthenticationManager = new MyServiceAuthenticationManager();
serviceHost.Authorization.ExternalAuthorizationPolicies = 
    new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.IdentityModel.Policy.IAuthorizationPolicy>(
        new MyAuthorizationPolicy[] { new MyAuthorizationPolicy() });
```

As I know, in the `ServiceAuthorizationManager` inherited class, in `CheckAccessCore` method, a `return false` statement indicates an **Access Denied**. That's all good till I want the client side to know that he got an access denied exception where the service stops returning anything to the client and it seems the service thread hanged.

I tried all kinds of `try catch` in the client side and even added a `FaultContract` to the operation, but the problem resists.

All I can see are two error events in Diagnostics Tools.

[image]

What are missing from my implementations to get the service inform the user on access denied error?

**Update**

It's notable to say that I'm using `RoutingService` and now I guess the real cause is that `RoutingService` is somehow eating the exception but I don't know exactly where that happens. Even though I stepped into every possible method but I failed to find it.

**Update 2**

I have `IErrorHandler` in place:

```
   public class ServiceErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            //You can log th message if you want.            
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message msg)
        {
            if (error is FaultException)
                return;

            FaultException faultException = new FaultException(error.Message);
            MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
            msg = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
        }
    }
```

But event with this the calling client wont' get the exception and the same 'unhandled exception' will appear in debug events.

The sole way that I can fail the calling client is by throwing an exception in `BeforeSendReply` method of `IDispatchMessageInspector` which I think isn't the way to go as I get a `CommunicationException` on the client side instead of `FaultException`:

```
  public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {                        
        if (reply != null && reply.IsFault)
        {
            var messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(reply, Int32.MaxValue);
            throw new FaultException("Access was denied", messageFault.Code);
        }
    }
```

WCF Tracing:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what happens when you are expecting an "Access Denied" error to be returned? And could you perhaps post some of the relevant client-side code? One final thought: a thread hanging when it should be returning an error suggests multi-threading weirdness; could there be an unnoticed deadlock or race condition in how the exception is being triggered/handled?

Comment: You might also want to see [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738305/wcf-routing-service-dynamic-error-handling)

Comment: Did you try turning on WCF tracing? This may give you more information on what's going on on the server side.

Comment: @F.StephenQ, look at the updates. I even tried to encapsulate the client code into a `Task` and getting its exception from outside, but yet again, this time the Task will freeze.

Comment: @MvdD, Yes I have WCF Tracing enabled. Look at updates.

Comment: What is the call for your service? which line?

Comment: I had a similar issue - maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231970/ierrorhandler-returning-wrong-message-body-when-http-status-code-is-401-unauthor

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect a FaultException here but instead, a Communication Exception, in your case a [SecurityAccessDeniedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securityaccessdeniedexception(v=vs.110).aspx). I would expect all the exceptions raised at this stage to be communication one as it is about communication issue, security ones are part of it.

Comment: the problem is not type of the exception, but rather it is that the exception is swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change code type as follows:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I'm using TCP with Transport+Message security.

Comment: Please try with <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past and the solution was to grant permissions to the account assigned to the appPool in the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog`